# Can the taxonomist badge be awarded more than once?

Tags: discussion, badges, taxonomist-badge

Can the taxonomist badge be awarded more than once?

I would think so, but there are only 874 badges awarded and over 1500 tags that have been used 50+ times.  The definition states *"Created a tag used by 50 questions"*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> EDIT not by Jeff:
>
> "Current the Taxonomist badge is not awarded multiple times. [This] answer is over 2 years old, so I'll clarify what the current intent is when Jeff gets back from vacation." – Nick Craver♦ [[Nov 30, 2011](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114220/131713)]

Yes, it can be awarded more than once.

And tags can also be created by anonymous users who eventually get culled.

https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/02/when-is-an-account-abandoned/

Comment: Ah.  Culled users.  Never occurred to me.  Humph.

Comment: Recently, it was brought to my attention that taxonomist badge can only be awarded once. See [FAQ](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/68258/202617).

Comment: _"can be awarded more than once"_ is wrong (outdated) answer: [List of all badges with full descriptions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions) says: "awarded once"