# Why wasn't I awarded [taxonomist] badge for tag [matlab-load]?

Tags: support, badges, taxonomist-badge

I created a tag [matlab-load](/questions/tagged/matlab-load) to disambiguate [load](/questions/tagged/load) (see: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/184606/202617).
The tag is used more than 50 times (last time I checked).

I would like to know why wasn't I awarded Taxonomist badge?

Comment: Are you certain you created the tag? Is it possible that the owner of the first question with the tag would be the one who "created" it, and not an editor?

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII two things: (1) I'm not 100% certain I am the creator of the tag because I have no way of seeing who created a tag (I looked in meta quite a bit to see where this information can be found - but couldn;t locate it)

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII (2) Most tags are created by people asking questions . However some are created by poeple trying to make sense of it all and put some order to things by editing and dis-ambiguaing tags like I did. I feel it is not less important to create and add tags this way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Taxonomist badge is [awarded once](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/68258/187824) and you are [already awarded the badge](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/11/taxonomist?userid=1714410) for the tag [bsxfun](/questions/tagged/bsxfun).

Comment: I was lead to believe taxonomist badge [can be awarded more than once](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/52/202617). So what is the current policy with this badge?

Comment: @Shai - At present it is awarded once as per FAQ.

Comment: Thank you for clearing this up.