# All answers on "Deleted Recent Answers" page are linked to <question-URL>/0#0

Tags: bug, status-completed, hyperlinks, deleted-posts-pages

All answers on "Deleted Recent Answers" are linked as `<question-URL>/0#0` which is not redirecting us to our deleted answer. For e.g. the link of one of my deleted answer is giving like this:

`http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184678/why-wasnt-i-awarded-taxonomist-badge-for-tag-matlab-load/0#0`

I think it should redirect us to the standard URL like `<question-URL>/<answer-id>#<answer-id>` for e.g.

`http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184678/why-wasnt-i-awarded-taxonomist-badge-for-tag-matlab-load/184679#184679`

In short just replace `0` with `answer-id` in `0#0`.

> [image]

Comment: PS: In the given example I have one deleted and one accepted answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This was fixed in the latest deploy, the deleted answer in question should always be directly linked to now.

Comment: "[Thanks for reporting this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts)"...

Comment: (RE: edit, I think a response of "[I AM ABOVE THE LAW!](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T-jXe0x4YdM)" would have been acceptable too)

Comment: @TimStone Alas, but I'm not.  Yet.